# Automatically add closing slash to singleton tags like "img" and "br"

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I need a way to automatically add a closing slash to singleton HTML tags without an end slash. I tried using PHP Tidy with "XHTML" set as true, but it doesn't make a difference. I'm fine with using some other validator instead of PHP Tidy, I just need a way to resolve this issue without some lame `str_replace` function.

```
# Tidy (repair HTML)
$tidy_config = array(
                     'clean' => true,
                     'output-xhtml' => true,
                     'show-body-only' => true,
                     'wrap' => 0,
                     );

$tidyHTML = tidy_parse_string($content, $tidy_config, 'UTF8');
$tidyHTML->cleanRepair();
```

Comment: please add the code that you tried with an example string so we can help

Comment: Your code works for me. It adds the slashes.

Comment: Just to be sure, you know this doesn't modify `$content`, right?

Comment: Yeah, I understand $tidyHTML is the output.